# Заполнение модой пропусков в столбцах с категориальными значениями

Tags: python, pandas

Прошу помощи!
Есть условный датафрейм (q) с категориальными значениями в столбцах, в которых есть пропуски.
Хочу заполнить пропуски модой, с созданием нового фрейма (w) однако код:

```
w = fillna(q.mode())
```

заполняет пропуски модой только в первой строке нового фрейма.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Comment: настоятельно рекомендую в подобных вопросах добавлять свой код и пример исходных данных в воспроизводимом виде.

Answer (score 2):

удивительно, что ваш код вообще что-то заполняет. ошибка ваша в том, что метод `.mode()` возвращает датафрейм, а при заполнении NaN датафреймом получается именно то, что получается у вас. поэтому нужно результат `mode()` перевести в словарь или серию для маппинга значений по столбцам, и уже ей заполнять:

```
df2 = df.fillna(df.mode().squeeze())
```

или

```
df2 = df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])
```

или

```
df2 = df.fillna(df.mode().to_dict("records")[0])
```